# FileMaker: Allow the user to filter the table and then revert back to showing all records

Tags: filemaker

I've just started using FileMaker Pro. I have created a spreadsheet in Excel which I'm basically trying to recreate in FileMaker.

I have my table (or, Portal) set up with data. Above the table I have 3 drop down fields, which pull their values from the table below. Based off of the value of the drop down fields, I want a GO button that will filer all of the table items to match what is in the 3 drop downs.

Image the table contains Car, Colour, Year. If the user selects Mercedes, Red, 1980 from the 3 drop down fields, I want the table to only show results that match those fields.

Ideally I'd like a button to trigger this action, and another button that resets it so it shows all results.

I can see that you can filter the table when you double click it, but this seems to set it to permanently filter. I want a button to do it basically.

Would appreciate the help! Thanks

Comment: Yes, a portal is filtered permanently. But you can use a 4th field (or a variable) to hold the decision whether to apply the filters or not, and use it in your filtering expression.

Comment: Alternatively, you could make the filter pass all records when there is no selection. Then you won't need the button or the additional field/variable.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I managed to find a way to do it by adding a button, setting the action to Single Step, and then adding 'Find Matching Records' and setting it to 'Constrain' and then I selected the first drop down value.

The weird thing is it seems to automatically filter based on the other drop downs too which I didn't tell it to do. So that works, but I'm just realising that when I change the drop down value It actually changes the first row's data to be whatever I'm setting the drop down to. Is there a way to stop the drop down from writing to the table?

Comment: I am afraid you have lost me at this point. In your question, you have described a portal. A portal shows related records, and is unaffected by any find operations. The exception is a master-detail layout where a portal shows the current found set - but such portal cannot be filtered.

Comment: If a row is selected, when I change a drop down that is above the table, it will change the row's value based on the drop down value. Whereas I just want my row to show values from the table, not have the ability to change them

Comment: Sorry, this is not getting any clearer. I suggest you join one of the forums dedicated to the Filmmaker platform, where you can have an extended discussion and post example files.